# Create .pyi files automatically?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

How can I automatically create the boilerplate code of [pyi](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) files?

I want to create a [pyi](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) file for type hinting as described in [pep484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) which contains all method names.

I don't want magic. I want to add the type information after auto creating the file.

I want to avoid the copy+paste work.

Goal: Type hinting in PyCharm for Python2.

Comment: What is the module that you're creating the `pyi` file for written in?

Comment: @rakslice I want type hinting for python files. But this question is outdated. We are in the process of switching from Python2 to Python3 in the next months.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, there is no such direct tool in PyCharm. There are, however, 3rd party tools for this.

---

## `.pyi` generators

### [MyPy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/)

Yes, I guess anyone who wants to use compile-time type checking in Python, probably ends up using MyPy. MyPy contains [stubgen.py](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/stubgen.py) tool which generates `.pyi` files.

#### Usage

```
mkdir out
stubgen urllib.parse
```

generates `out/urllib/parse.pyi`.

You can use it wit Python2 too:

```
stubgen --py2 textwrap
```

And for C modules:

```
scripts/stubgen --docpath <DIR>/Python-3.4.2/Doc/library curses
```

If you want to specify the path to your custom package, you can use `--search-path` option:

```
stubgen my-pkg --search-path=folder/path/to/the/package
```

### [make-stub-files](https://github.com/edreamleo/make-stub-files)

This project is dedicated to exactly this goal.

#### Usage

A very basic one (but it has a handful of options, just consult `README.md` or `make_stub_files -h`

```
make_stub_files foo.py
```

---

## pre-written `.pyi` files

So you don't have to write your own.

### [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed)

Yes, if you're using `.pyi` files in your own project, you probably want to use this also when using external code. Typeshed contains `.pyi` files for Python2 and Python3 stdlib and a bunch of Python2 libraries (like [redis](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/2/redis), [crypto](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/2and3/Crypto), ...) and some Python3 libraries (like [werkzeug](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/3/werkzeug) or [requests](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/2and3/requests)), all nicely versioned.

---

## PyCharm alternatives to `.pyi` files

In case you're lazy, or simply just working on a project which doesn't require `.pyi` files and you don't want to be bothered by using 3rd party tools, PyCharm allows you to use:

- [Type docstrings](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#legacy) (legacy)
- [Python 3 function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Comment: i would like to use `stubgen`, but am a little confused on how to specify the custom path to my package directory.  I can't seen to find it.  Is it possible to include an example for this?

Comment: @jonathan: I currently have no access to a Python installation with MyPy, but the code says you should be able to use [`--search_path` option](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/9e564e1b1bf86a1bc72f432e9a2dfd49703319eb/mypy/stubgen.py#L78). I have added it to the answer, but if you try it out, please give me feedback if it doesn't work so I can fix it.

Comment: The option is `'--search-path'`, without an underscore.  I tried that first, but it failed...

Comment: @jonathan oh yes, naturally, it's a dash, not an underscore. My bad. Thank you for pointing that out, I've fixed this.

Comment: @sjaustirni how do you do this programmatically? Can stubgen.py be imported like a library and used in code?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a makefile for this:

```
package := example
sources := $(wildcard $(package)/*.py)

stub: $(sources)
    stubgen --output . --package $(package)

dist: setup.py stub
    python $< sdist bdist_wheel

publish: dist
    twine upload dist/*

.PHONY += stub dist publish
```

Running `make publish` will generate the `.pyi` files in the same location as their corresponding `.py` files before packaging and uploading to PyPI. They will be included in the package [provided that they are part of `package_data`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data).