# How do you check if a typeshed stub (.pyi) file matches the implementation?

Tags: python, typeshed, python-typing

You can use mypy's `stubgen.py` or some other tools to [generate `.pyi` files automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602541/create-pyi-files-automatically), but stubgen contains the additional suggestion to check the stub files for accuracy.

If I autogenerated stubs then modified them to fix errors or make things more stringent that weren't picked up on by the generator, how can I then check that they agree with the implementation? Or as the implementation changes and I had hand-generated files, how can I make sure they stay in sync?

Answer (score 5):

I found this question as a result of needing to do this too, so here is what I've subsequently found...

[Apparently, a tool called stubtest was recently added to mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5028#issuecomment-740101546) (undocumented currently) which will validate the stubs against the implementation insofar as is possible. Here is a contrived example:

```
$ cat <<EOF > simple.py
> def thing(obj):
>     if isinstance(obj, float):
>         return 0.0
>     elif isinstance(obj, int):
>         return 0
>     else:
>         raise TypeError("Unsupported type passed to thing.")
> 
> EOF
```

I create a stubfile which uses knowledge of the implementation to write a specific type annotation (definitely not auto-generated - that would be hard to do!):

```
$ cat <<EOF > simple.pyi
> from typing import Any, Union
> 
> def thing(obj: Union[float, int]): ...
> 
> EOF
```

Running stubtest yeilds no output, and a zero exit code:

```
$ python -m mypy.stubtest simple

$ echo $?
0
```

Now I update the implementation to have another argument:

```
cat <<EOF > simple.py
> def thing(obj, something_else):
>     if isinstance(obj, float):
>         return 0.0
>     elif isinstance(obj, int):
>         return 0
>     else:
>         raise TypeError("Unsupported type passed to thing.")
> 
> EOF
```

And re-run the stubtest:

```
$ python -m mypy.stubtest simple
error: simple.thing is inconsistent, stub does not have argument "something_else"
Stub: at line 3
def (obj: Union[builtins.float, builtins.int]) -> Any
Runtime: at line 1 in file stub-testing/simple.py
def (obj, something_else)

$ echo $?
1
```

I'm still fairly weak in my understanding of the mypy search path, and couldn't get the direct `stubtest` entrypoint to work (as opposed to the `python -m mypy.stubtest` form).

I didn't yet test this against anything more complex than this toy example - I suspect there is a lot of devil in the detail.

Comment: (author of stubtest here)
stubtest is now documented here https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubtest.html
when running as just stubtest (and not python -m mypy.stubtest) you might need to specify PYTHONPATH explicitly

Comment: I still can't get the search path to work, even using `python -m`. Very frustrating.